# What's the difference between "Suggestion" and "Refactoring Only" in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, editorconfig

I am building my .editorconfig for my project. I see both "Suggestion" and "Refactoring Only" for several of the options. What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-options?view=vs-2022#severity-level)

Violations of a `Suggestion` appear as build messages and as suggestions in the Visual Studio IDE; see the `Messages` section in the `Error list`.

[image]

---

The description for `Silent` applies to `Refactoring only`, as it will be saved as such in `.editorconfig`, e.g.:

```
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_should_be_begins_with_i.severity = silent
```

Violations of a `Refactoring Only`/`silent` rule aren't visible to the user, but the `Quick Actions and Refactorings...` menu shows an entry to resolve the violation (similarly as for `Suggestion` violations).

A closed issue on the Microsoft Visual Studio documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/6263#issuecomment-754325624) says:

> Do not show anything to the user when this rule is violated. Code
> generation features generate code in this style, however. Rules with
> silent severity participate in cleanup and appear in the Quick Actions
> and Refactorings menu.